# Why am I receiving "AttributeError:" in this beautifulsoup webscraping program and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on a program which scrapes prices. It was working at one point, but randomly stopped today. I checked the url and the id to make sure that nothing changed. What's up with my program? My objective is to get the price of an item off an amazon page and get it to print.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Simple-Solution-Enzymatic-Pro-Bacteria-Cleaning/dp/B0002I9OA2/ref=sxin_3_osp54-e3cdf75e_cov?ascsubtag=e3cdf75e-7df2-4a39-8c03-29ea3c01f579&creativeASIN=B0002I9OA2&cv_ct_id=amzn1.osp.e3cdf75e-7df2-4a39-8c03-29ea3c01f579&cv_ct_pg=search&cv_ct_wn=osp-search&keywords=dog+urine&linkCode=oas&pd_rd_i=B0002I9OA2&pd_rd_r=16714614-0531-4896-adbb-9a6a0a255667&pd_rd_w=Z7DSH&pd_rd_wg=n1nMs&pf_rd_p=53eff971-6e12-4016-9864-b6dfd929b2b3&pf_rd_r=SMFAZPA12ZRYCG72PCFA&qid=1573597499&tag=42987st350sr-20'

headers = {"User Agent":"#enter your user agent"}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

# obj= soup.find(id="titleSection").get_text()
print(price)
```

This is the error I'm getting if I run it:

```
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Can you please post the full error that you´re getting

Answer (score 2):

When you run:

```py
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
```

You get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 12, in <module>
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

because it can't find an element which id is "priceblock_ourprice"

If you use a debugger and examine the *page* response, you get an HTML page without this ID.